# Why can't I use a generic method to implement multiple typed interfaces in C#?

Tags: c#, interfaces

```
public class B { }
public class C { }
public class D { }
public class E { }

public class A :
    IRetrievable<B, C>,
    IRetrievable<D, E>
{
    public TValue Retrieve<TKey, TValue>(TKey input)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

What is the reason I can't do this? Visual Studio is telling me that the interfaces aren't being implemented, even though they could be via putting types B, C and D, E in TKey, TValue, respectively.

Comment: Well, you've specified two interfaces, but only implemented one (which one?).  Even if you implemented the other, how would C# tell the difference between the two, since they are both exactly the same signature?

Comment: I was hoping the compiler would be clever and know that it can use the same implementation for both, since both fit into the same method.

Comment: actually i don't think this works with even a single interface

Comment: @Ewan It doesn't, and I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generic type will have the actual types used in the code added at compile time.

Here you are confusing Method and class generic types

```
public class B { }
public class C { }
public class D { }
public class E { }

public class A :
    IRetrievable<B, C> //interface not implemented!!
{
    public TValue Retrieve<TKey, TValue>(TKey input)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public interface IRetrievable<T1, T2>
{
    T1 Retrieve(T2 input);
}

public void Main()
{
    var a = new A()
    a.Retrieve<D,E>(new D());
}
```

Here A should implement IRetrievable for A and B. but the method is called with D and E and so a class A_DandE will be created which doesn't match the interface

A *must* implement the interface as specified, but the actual implementation is defined by the calling code and as such cant be guaranteed when you just compile A on its own

working code:

```
public class A :
    IRetrievable<B, C>, 
    IRetrievable<D, E>
{
    public B Retrieve(C input)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public D Retrieve(E input)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Here A implements both methods as defined by the interfaces

Comment: _I guess!_ In my particular use case it would save so much time if I could do this. Oh well.

Comment: @TimMorris this could be a job for [T4](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2019). For example, you can keep your generic implemention on your class, then generate a [class part](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods) with T4 which implements the interfaces delegating to it.

Answer (score 1):

Use composition instead.  Pass implementations of your two interfaces as parameters into the constructor of your class, and assign each one to an `IRetrievable<T, K>` member of your class.

Alternatively, inherit from a dual interface:

```
public interface IDualRetrievable
{
    IRetrievable<T, K> Retrievable1 { get; set; }
    IRetrievable<T, K> Retrievable2 { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass : IDualRetrievable
```

If you wish, you can pass the *same* implementation for each interface instance.